# Three JS: не отображается текстура.

Tags: html, three.js, javascript

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблемка: не отображается наложенная на объект текстура (размером 1000х1000).
Вот код создания:

```
var texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sand.jpg');
var cube, cube_geometry, cube_texture;
            cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 1, 100);
            cube_texture  = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture1});
            //cube_texture  = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            cube          = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry, cube_texture);
            scene.add(cube);
```

Установлено глобальное освещение, с MeshNormalMaterial объект отображается.

Answer (score 1):

В гугле хроме текстуры грузятся только через сервер (из соображений безопасности). Например, можешь работать с текстурами через денвер. Возможно, в браузере можно в настройках понизить требования безопасности, не пробовал.

Кроме того, стороны текстуры должны быть равны степени двойки (но не обязательно равны друг другу). Т.е.128px, 64px, и т.д.